# Что нужно сделать, чтобы из переменной None сделать другую в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я не понимаю, как код переделать, чтобы он работал...

## test.py

```
import lang
import time

time.sleep(1)

lang.ru = 1

lang.up()

print(lang.ru)
print(lang.start)
```

## lang.py

```
ru = None
start = None

def up():
    if(ru == 0):

        # Eng
    
        start = "Hello"

    else:  

        # Rus

        start = "Привет"
```

Как сделать чтобы оно работало?

Comment: При команде print(lang.start) выдает None, хотя должно быть слово: Привет или Hello

Comment: Прописывая присваивание внутри функции, вы создаёте только локальную переменную, которая существует только внутри функции. Если вы хотите менять глобальную переменную, то нужно прописать `global start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def up():
    nonlocal start
    nonlocal ru
    ....
```

Или через global

Питон думает что старт это новая локальная переменная и не перезаписывает глобальную.